# Kafka streams - is it the right approach?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, concurrency

I am trying to tackle the following scenario, possibly using kafka streams and interactive queries.

Imagine an event e that triggers 500 (or any amount) clients to make a request to a RESTful backend. From these 500 requests, let's assume half have a parameter set of X and the other half have parameter set of Y. What the backend needs to do is to compute something only twice (as much as the amount of parameters set) and return back to clients some result.

My idea is to create topic for the first request that arrives of each parameter set, compute it,  and all subsequent will query the local store for results. Would that be feasible? Is there some  more efficient way I am not aware of?

Comment: *What the backend needs to do is to compute something only twice*, looks like *request-process-response*, why do you want to use Kafka here?

Comment: I was thinking the consumer - producer, one input, one output and use its localstore for persistance/statefulness.
The "twice" is only an example, can be a whole bunch of parameter set ending up with a bunch of streams.